# Having Trouble With InputMaps and ActionMaps in Java

Tags: java

TLDR: For whatever reason, my inputs only work half the time.

So I'm trying to learn Java more proficiently, and as an exercise, I'm trying to recreate Pong.
I've created a JFrame, and a JPanel within that to contain the elements of the game separated into different classes to keep them organized. When I launch the game, I'd like the W key to decrease the playerY value to move the drawn rectangle up, and when I hit S, I'd like to increase the playerY value moving it down. I'm sure it's something silly, but when I launch the program, the W key input only works half the time, and the S key doesn't work at all. I read through various forums, and they suggested to others that sometimes issues similar to this can be caused by window focus, so I added RequestFocus() to pull focus to the window, which seems to work, but my key inputs still only work half way. I've been reading through forums, and trying to troubleshoot for a couple hours including reading the Oracle documentation, but I figured a second set of eyes would probably help at this point.

Thank you for any help.

Here's the code within the panel:

```
    int playerX = 20;
    int playerY = 200;
    InputMap inputMap = new InputMap();
    ActionMap actionMap = new ActionMap();
    Panel(){
        //Requesting Focus so that the inputmap gets grabbed.
        requestFocus();
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //Creating inputs.
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W,0),"wPressed");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,0),"sPressed");
        //Mapping inputs to ActionMap Classes.
        actionMap.put("wPressed", new wKeyPressed());
        actionMap.put("SPressed", new sKeyPressed());
        //When the component is focused, use this inputmap and actionmap.
        setInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,inputMap);
        setActionMap(actionMap);
    }

    //Creating Key Classes below.

    //W Key Pressed Class.
    public class wKeyPressed extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("W Key Pressed");
            playerY = playerY - 20;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    //S Key Pressed.
    public class sKeyPressed extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("S Key Pressed");
            playerY = playerY + 20;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    //Painting Components.
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(playerX,playerY,5,30);
    }
```

Read through various other Stack answers, and read Oracle documentation to make sure everything looked right.
When the W key is pressed, the rectangle should move up, when the S key is pressed, the rectangle should move down.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

You have a character-case typo. Code should be

```
actionMap.put("sPressed", new sKeyPressed());
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed half the problem, now the S key works some of the time, but when launched, sometimes, neither key works. Even when I click to pull focus to the window sometimes the keys just don't work.

Comment: Then *that* problem is not shown in your code, since it *always* works in my implementation. You need to open a new question with the right (full [runnable] and failing) code